# MySQL storing tables in table

Tags: c#, mysql, data-structures

Is it possible to store tables in table in MySQL?
I have data like this:

```
class Item
{
 private struct Counts
        {
            public string ID;
            public decimal qty;
        }
 public UInt32 ID;
 private List<Counts> List_Item;
}
```

How to properly store this data in MySQL?
Im not sure, having separate table that contains Count for each Item is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly store this data in MySQL? Im not sure, having separate
>   table that contains Count for each Item is a good idea.

Why not looking at the C# class en struct you have an OneToMany relation.
One Item has many Counts.

So you tables should look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE item (

    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
);

CREATE TABLE item_count (

 , id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 , id_text VARCHAR(255) 
 , qty DECIMAL
 , PRIMARY KEY(item_count_id)
 , KEY(item_id) 
);
```

**Note that you should always use an PRIMARY KEY in a table (when using InnoDB storage engine) read more about that here -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184 (post off mine)**